# Pig & MongoDB - How to load document nested fields with MongoLoader?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-pig, nosql

I have a set of document stored on mongodb, which are like this

> {
>
> > "_id" : { "$oid" : "5201ca52ddf19f9c7aea0bb2"} ,
> >
> > "id" : 1 ,
> >
> > "path" : "C://..." ,
> >
> > "experiences" : [
> >
> > > > { id = "1", date="12/2012", content="blabla" }
> > > >
> > > > { id = "2", date="12/2013", content="blabla2" }
> >
> > ]
>
> }

I would like to process the "experiences" fields of these documents to obtain an output like this:
(1,1,12/2012,blabla)

(1,2,12/2013,blabla2)

the schema is (document_id,exp_id,exp_date,exp_content).

I'm loading the document via pig and MongoLoader, here is my code:

```
REGISTER /root/mongo-2.10.1.jar
REGISTER /root/pig_librairies/mongo-hadoop_cdh4.3.0-1.1.0.jar
REGISTER /root/pig_librairies/mongo-hadoop-pig_cdh4.3.0-1.1.0.jar
REGISTER /root/pig_librairies/mongo-hadoop-core_cdh4.3.0-1.1.0.jar

persons = LOAD 'mongodb://localhost/gestion_competences.cv'
      USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoLoader('id:chararray, path:chararray, experiences:charrarray)
      AS (id, path, experiences);
```

I know the problem is here:

```
experiences:chararray
```

but I don't know what structure i could use. I tried bags and maps and it doesn't work...

Do you have an idea on how to solve the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `experiences:map[]` and then you can access values via key as `experiences#'content'`